# Pagination in Apex/VisualForce for Custom Classes

Tags: visualforce

I'm a new programmer, I want to write a pagination and the style is same as the all contacts, but I dont't know how to write it. The pictures are as follows:
[image] 
[image: especially these parts:]

Comment: Refer my blog for some tips (Custom Controller Pagination - easiest way) http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/03/custom-controller-pagination-easiest-way.html

Comment: I want to use the style is the same as the picture,my pagination logical have achieved.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: yeah,I have tied these and I have read the HTML code of the picture,but I don't know how to transform the html tag to visualforce tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualforce actually has a pre-built component that provides (most) of the functionality you want using apex:enhancedList:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:enhancedList height="500" customizable="true" type="Contact"/>
</apex:page>
```

There's other ways of doing so as well, posted both on this site and others, so a simple search should yield the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your can refer below link for pagination.

> [Page Navigation with help of list wrapper class in sales force](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/salesforce/10744/page-navigation-with-help-of-list-wrapper-class-in-sales-force#t=201708020433084149174)
>
> [pagination-using-standard-set-controller-salesforce](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/pagination-using-standard-set-controller-salesforce/)
>
> [Repository Link](https://bitbucket.org/nitheshk/pagenavigation)